# setting up cookie in my php script when user login but not getting anything set

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

So i am searching on here from some days but could not find a proper solution,well my problem is i have my login system ready and working but the problem is when i am trying to set cookie when my check box is checked its not setting up a cookie.
i have three files

1. studentlogin.php(user interface)
2. loginprocess.js(jquery that contains ajax method for calling login.php)
3. login.php(actual logic)
4. studentlogin.php

   ```
           <?php
               session_start();
               if(isset($_cookie['eno']))
                   {
                       header('location:profile.php');
                       exit();
                   }
       ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang='en'>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>LMS | Login</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/processlogin.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div id="wrap">
       <?php include 'header.php';?>
       <div id="content">
       <section>
           <article id="logform">
               <form action="" id="log">
                   <fieldset>
                   <legend>Login Here</legend>
                       <table>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <label for="eno">Enrollment No:<span class='err' id='err_eno'>*Require</span></label>
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>  
                       <input type="text" name="eno" id="eno" value="" placeholder='Enter Enrollment No' required/>  
                       </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <label for="pw">Password:<span class='err' id='err_pw'>*Require</span></label>
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" value="" placeholder='Your Password' required/>
                       </td>

                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked="checked">
                       <label>Keep me signed in.</label>
                       </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                       <td colspan='2'>
                       <span id="err"></span>
                       </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Login" />
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
                       </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <label>New user?<a href="studentregistration.php">Register here</a></label>
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                       <label>Forgot your password?<a href="resetpassword.php">Click here</a></label>
                       </td>
                       </tr>
                       </table>
                   </fieldset>
               </form>
           </article>
       </section>
       </div>
       <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```
5. loginprocess.php

   ```
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(){

               var dataString = $('#log').serialize();
               //alert (dataString);return false;  
           $.ajax({
                       type:"POST",
                       url:"script/login.php",
                       data:dataString,
                       success:function(x)
                       {
                            if(x =='')
                           {
                                //Handle Error Here
                                $('#err').html("<p class='err'>Please provide right combination</p>");
                           }
                           else if(x == '1')
                           {
                               window.location='profile.php';
                           }

                       }
                   });
           return false;
           });
   ```
6. login.php

   ```
           <?php
       error_reporting(0);
       session_start();
       include "../db/connect.php";
       $password = $_POST['pw'];
       $eno = $_POST['eno'];

       $password_hash = md5($password);
       if(!empty($eno) && !empty($password))
       {

           $query ="select * from users where eno = '$eno' AND password = '$password_hash'";
           $result = $db->query($query);
           if($result->num_rows)
               {
                   $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['eno'];
                   //echo"<script>alert($_SESSION['login']);</script>"
                   if(isset($_POST['cb']))
                       {

                           setcookie("eno",$eno,time()+3600);  
                       }
                   echo '1';

               }
           else
               {
                   setcookie('eno','',time()-3600);
                   session_regenerate_id();
                   session_destroy();
                   echo '';
               }
       }
       else
       {
           session_regenerate_id();
           session_destroy();
       }
       ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks obviously wrong but the fact that your $_cookie should be $_COOKIE

```
session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE['eno']))
{
    header('location:profile.php');
    exit();
}
```

Hope this was it.

Comment: okay i forgot to change it after i made a change,but this is not the problem because i am setting up cokie in login.php and echoing it out on profile.php page upon successfull login but its not showing cookie named 'eno',which i am setting in login.php

Comment: there is no action set for the form from the studentlogin.php page - i assume the action must be login.php

Comment: not really - especially when you called it loginprocess.php
try to change the submit's button type from "submit" to "button" and check if the request is made

Comment: thanx for support finally solved it my self,the problem was setting up cookie for current directory i specified the root as directory and its done!!!!!

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['cb']))
                    {
                        setcookie("eno",$eno,time()+3600,'/');  
                    }`